# Job history date changes after Jenkins upgrade

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I upgraded Jenkins recently.. from a very old 1.5x version to 1.6x version. After starting Jenkins, I noticed that all job history shows dec31 1969 date and time. How can I correct this and bring it back to actual date and time.

If this is not possible, I want to get rid of each job history with old date and time without going to each job configuration. How can I do this?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> If this is not possible, I want to get rid of each job history with
>   old date and time without going to each job configuration. How can I
>   do this?

I'm going to answer this part of the question. I'm also assuming you have access to the Scripting Console in Jenkins. (http://yourJenkinsUrl.com/script)

You can print all the builds that Jenkins knows about with this command:

```
Jenkins.instance.allItems.each {
  j -> j.builds.each { b -> println b }
}
```

And [this script](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins-scripts/blob/master/scriptler/bulkDeleteBuilds.groovy) shows you can delete each build simply by calling delete() once you have a reference to it. Combining these scripts will let you delete all the existing builds.

Comment: Hi Jeanne, thanks for your reply. Do you know why the date and time changes in first place ? And if there is a time plugin or something to change it ?

Comment: I'm going with 'bug" as for why it happened. I saw it happen to. I don't know why it happened. I do know that new builds didn't exhibit the behavior so in that respect at least it is only a one time problem.